# How to finish Loading View only when inner Iframes are done loading MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iframe, .net-core

I have a DotNet CORE MVC project.
The project has a controller which receives an array of strings, each string represents an Iframe source that needs to be placed in the View.

The model takes the array of string and do some manipulation on them, which means that eventually when the model is done and passed to the view it has a list of strings ready to be used as an iframe SRC.

The list in the model is this -

```
        public List<string> IFramePixels { get; set; };
```

And this is my View -

```
<body>
    @foreach (string iframe in Model.IFramePixels)
    {
        <iframe width='1' height='1' frameborder='0' src='@iframe'></iframe>
    }
</body>
```

Everything works fine, the question is how can I delay the view loading finish time to when all those inner Iframes are done loading.

The reason I want that is that some outside website gonna place my website as an Iframe, and they need to know when all the inner Iframes are done (so I can't use a simple JS listener), I wanted to tell them to do some sort of a listener on when my webpage is done loading which means that the inner Iframes are done as well.

Thanks!

Edit ->
Well.. still couldn't find any answer, maybe thats simply not possible?
Does anyone have some different approach that might get me what I need? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> need to know when all the inner Iframes are done...

Your sentence reminded me of **Promise.All** in Javascript.

So, if I got you right, `jQuery.when()` can serve your intention.
In addition, to make sure the page load is not made until all iframes are loaded, you can use [$.holdReady](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/)

A sample code to get you on the way:

```
<div>
    <iframe id="if1" src="./let.html" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
    <iframe id="if2" src="./let.html" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
    <iframe id="if3" src="./let.html" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
</div>

<script src="./jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // call this at the top of your script to delay jQuery's ready event.
    $.holdReady(true);

    var d1 = $.Deferred();
    var d2 = $.Deferred();
    var d3 = $.Deferred();

    $('#if1').on('load', function() {
        alert('iframe 1 Loaded');
        d1.resolve();
    });
    $('#if2').on('load', function() {
        alert('iframe 2 Loaded');
        d2.resolve();
    });
    $('#if3').on('load', function() {
        alert('iframe 3 Loaded');
        d3.resolve();
    });

    $.when(d1, d2, d3).done(function(v1, v2, v3) {
        alert(' All iframes loaded');
        $.holdReady(false); // this allows document.ready to begin

        // your logic here ...
        // At this moment, all iframes are loaded ...
    });


    $(document).ready(function() {            
        alert('This page just now finished Loading');
    });
</script>
```

The sequence of alerts clearly shows what happens. As you can see, jQuery.when() provides a way to execute callback functions based on objects that represent asynchronous events. Please check the [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) if needed.

Finally, since you're inserting the `<iframe>` tags dynamically, consider the following code:

```
        $.holdReady(true); // delay page load until all iframes get loaded


        var defer_Array = [];
        $.each($('iframe'), (index, tag) => {

            let temp = $.Deferred();
            defer_Array.push(temp);


            $(tag).on('load', function() {
                alert('iframe loaded #' + index);
                (defer_Array[index]).resolve();
            });
        })


        $.when(...defer_Array).done(function(v1, v2, v3) {
            alert(' All iframes loaded');
            $.holdReady(false); 
            // your logic here ...
        });
```

Feel free to grab the code and tweak it as you wish ... :)

Comment: Hey mate!, first of all thanks for the elaborated answer.
Please refer to the part in my question where I explained my scenario.
as some outside source is gonna use my website as an Iframe I need to make sure my page finish loading only when all of these inner iframes are, thats why having a simple js listener on my website isn't enough.

Customer A is using my system, he place the pixel (my website) on his page and needs to know programtically when those inner iframes are done loading.

Comment: So, you mean your page contains iframes, while the page itself will be rendered inside an iframe tog on the customer's page. It seems the above solution needs to be performed on your customer's side too. Not sure, but simulating that delay through overriding `OnResultExecuted` method of `Result Filters` in MVC might help. You can read more here https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-filters/

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I mean.
The client can do your intial suggestion only if I can simulate the delay as you said.
OnResultExecuted is being handled before the view is loaded in the customers end, so the iframes won't even start.

Comment: I updated the answer for you, this time, adding `$.holdReady` to delay the page load until iframes get rendered.

Comment: Thanks for again for helping mate!, tried your solution but sadly failed... could you take a look maybe I did something wrong? edited my initial question with the attempt.

Comment: So, I probably did something wrong in my initial attempt, just kept trying and now it works perfectly also used your dynamic iframes part which works great.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmmm... could it be that without doing any JS, the page automatically delay its load till all the iframes are done loading? O.O
As the iframes aren't really dynamic once they reach the client? (the MVC creates the iframes dynamically but the html that actually being served is already with those iframes)

Comment: Thanks, I'm Happy it helped. I'll consider it, but as far as I know, JS fits the best for here.